# ZF2 Append value to array in php file with Zend\Config\Factory

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I try to add new value to array in php file with Zend\Config\Factory:

```
public function testFunc($testParam)
{
    $testArray = $this->testFunc1($testParam);

    if(!is_null($testArray[1])) {
         foreach ($testArray[1] as $array) {
             $this->testFunc($array);
        }
    }

    $filename = getcwd() . '/data/config/config.php';
    $configFile = \Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile($filename);

    $configFile[] = $testArray[0];

    if(!\Zend\Config\Factory::toFile($filename, $configFile)) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException("Can't put content to $filename.");
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is such that in `$filename` file saves only value from first function call and not from recursion.

**[UPDATE]**

I debug `\Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile` and found if I wanna to load php file, function load file that:

```
  ........
  $config = include $filepath;
```

in recursion `\Zend\Config\Factory::toFile` update my php file(i checked `config.php` file) and then in first function call `\Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile` get again php file without changes and overwrite `config.php`. As a consequence , is recorded only value from first function call in `config.php`.

Comment: Make sure the second call to the function is executed.

Comment: I checked, recursion is executed.

Comment: Where is `testFunc1`? What is in your array? You should add all valid information to your question so people can actually reproduce the issue. [Read also here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)